# What software to use for very basic rigged animations like this one?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation

this question may be really basic, but I am looking to create animations following a style like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-EJhnst6Kk) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWfSR5cs3uc). In case the links don't work, those should refer to the YouTube videos of 'Rock of Ages - All Cutscenes' and 'Zoot Woman - We Won't Break'.

What both of these videos have in common is this very basic shadow-puppet animation style of a few static images with a few simple joints. Is there any software you could recommend for these kinds of animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Duik with Adobe After Effect.

Duik is free! It's used for some professional projects that hit TV.

## [Duik download link](https://rainboxprod.coop/en/tools/duik/)

I recommend buying a real tutorial to learn how to get things setup properly. It helps to create a non destructive workflow. However, there are some free on YouTube tutorials out there (your mileage may vary).

[Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJgAUkjsomA)

### There are other programs by Adobe too such as Character Animator CC, or Animate CC (formerly known as Flash).

Answer (score 1):

while you can do this with after effects. I feel it is still easier to do this in a 3D animation tool like say:

- Blender
- Maya
- 3DS Max or something to that kind

as its more straightforward to set it up. Just a reminder just beacsue something is 3D does not mean it cant do 2D. While DUIK is cool and all remember most DCC 3d animation tools have the bones and rigging built into them on day one.